# R - gganimate : transition_reveal() doesn't respect my x-axis order

Tags: r, gganimate

I would like to animate the movements (in/out and charge) of a tramway line through its stops on the x-axis but when I use the transition_reveal() function from the gganimate package, the animation doesn't respect the order of the tramway stops on the axis. How can I solve the problem, please ?

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(gganimate)

tramway_df <- data.frame(
  stop_order = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17),
  stop_id = c(9943, 5041, 5361, 2902, 2903, 5872, 5802, 5803, 5804, 5805, 
               5710, 5711, 5712, 1643, 5714, 521, 529),
  stop_name = c("DA VINCI", "DA VINCI", "BORDET STATION", "VAN CUTSEM", "FONSON", "PAIX", 
            "TILLEUL", "HELMET", "FOYER SCHAERBEEK.", "WAELHEM", "VERBOEKHOVEN", "PAVILLON",
            "RUBENS", "LIEDTS", "THOMAS", "GARE DU NORD", "ROGIER"),
  stop_in = c(27, 102, 153, 141, 190, 317, 379, 438, 328, 214, 278, 298, 154, 144, 162, 185, 0),
  stop_out = c(0, 7, 3, 10, 22, 37, 81, 122, 143, 168, 291, 230, 149, 301, 412, 707, 821),
  stop_charge = c(27, 121, 271, 402, 571, 851, 1149, 1465, 1650, 1696, 1682, 1745, 1750, 1592, 1342, 821, 0)
)

tramway_df %>% 
  gather(movement, value, stop_in:stop_out) %>% 
  mutate(stop_id = factor(stop_id, levels = unique(stop_id))) %>% 
ggplot(aes(x=stop_id)) +
  geom_col(aes(y=value, fill = movement), position = "dodge", width = 1) +
  geom_line(aes(y=stop_charge, group=1)) + 
  scale_x_discrete(breaks = tramway_df$stop_id,
                   labels = tramway_df$stop_name) +
  transition_reveal(stop_charge)
```

Comment: Would changing it to transition_reveal(stop_order) give you your desired result?

Comment: Yes you're right ! :) Thank you very much @Lamia for your help !

Comment: @Lamia May I ask you how can I make my barcharts appears one by one so first stop_in and then stop_out and not stop_in and stop_out together ? Thanks a lot !